# Jqgrid search option for local datatype not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jqgrid

I want to add search option for my jqgrid table,

```
$('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: mydata,
    caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
    gridview: true,
    height: 'auto',
    colNames: ['title', 'color', 'fontsize'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'config.titlepage.title' },
        {name: 'config.titlepage.color' },
        {name: 'config.titlepage.fontsize' },
    ],
    pager: '#pageGrid'
    localReader: {
        id: "_id.$oid"
    }
});
$('#jqgrid').jqGrid('navGrid', "#pageGrid",
    { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false }, {}, {},
    { recreateFilter: true, overlay: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true});
```

I'm getting the search option but when I enter the search string and click on Filter button,  search is happening.

Please help me here, do I need add any library files to perform for this search filter?

Comment: You use very exotical values for `name` in `colModel` and `id` of `localReader`. Could you include some test data (the value of `mydata`) which you use?

Comment: Hi Oleg, here is the mydata value, var mydata = [
            {
                "_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090fa9"},
                "config": {
                    "titlepage": {
                        "title": "My First Title",
                        "color": true,
                        "fontsize": "42/44"
                    }
                }
            }            
        ];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which problem with searching you have. The only clear error is: you skip one `{}` in the list of `navGrid`. You current option of `navGrid` set delete options as searching options. Correct option will be

```
$('#jqgrid').jqGrid('navGrid', "#pageGrid",
    { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, {},
    { recreateFilter: true, overlay: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true});
```

Additionally you can consider to add `ignoreCase: true` option to the grid to make searching case insensitive. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DeepVeen0.htm) seems to work correctly.

Another option which you can use to read the same data: to use `datatype: 'jsonstring'`. In the case you can use `jsonmap` and choose more readable `name` property. In the case the internal `data` of grid will contains only the data which you need. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DeepVeen.htm) demonstrate this approach. It uses the following code

```
var mydata = [
        {
          "_id": {"$oid": "50a3f962b7718da1a3090fa9"},
          "config": { "titlepage": { "title": "My First Title", "color": true,
                                     "fontsize": "42/44" } } }
    ];

$('#jqgrid').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    datastr: mydata,
    caption: 'Titlepage Parameters',
    gridview: true,
    height: 'auto',
    colModel: [
        {name: 'title',    jsonmap: "config.titlepage.title" },
        {name: 'color',    jsonmap: "config.titlepage.color" },
        {name: 'fontsize', jsonmap: "config.titlepage.fontsize" },
    ],
    pager: '#pageGrid',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "_id.$oid"
    }
});
$('#jqgrid').jqGrid('navGrid', "#pageGrid",
    { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, {},
    { recreateFilter: true, overlay: true, multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true});
```

In any way I don't see any problem with searching in both demos.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, it worked for me. I have removed local datatype and used jsonString. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Is there any chance to make 'contains' as default instead of 'equal' in search filter.?

Comment: @DeepVeen: there are many ways to do this. For example you can specify `sopt` parameter of searching option (on the same level where `multipleGroup: true`). Alternatively you can use `cmTemplate` like `cmTemplate: {searchoptions: {sopt: ['cn', 'nc', 'eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni']}}`. Important is the first element in the array. It should be `"cn"`. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DeepVeen1.htm).

Comment: @DeepVeen: You are welcome! I'd recommend you to use [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) too. One can use both filter toolbar and advanced searching. The user can use more intuitive filter toolbar for simple filtering and one can use advanced searching dialog for more complex filters.

Comment: I just want to remove add subgroup button alone from my search  box. Is possible and how to do that?

Comment: @DeepVeen: Probably you should just remove `multipleGroup: true` option?